# Оптимизация MySQL запроса

Tags: mysql

Запрос, который медленно выполняется:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `tid`, `tsection`, `ttype`, `tcomments`, `tamount`, `tcount`, `tdone_count`, `tdel`, `tdel_admin`, `tsuccess`, `user_url`, `turl_full`, `social_type`, `diamond` 
  FROM `tasks` 
  WHERE `turl_full` NOT IN ('video22K6XaVfksA','userUCkLNWji7toIO7LisOM64Pkw','userUC9-ZDzx6MLlbuy-nSVjMsXw','userUCnXdo9ICrhRmu20MCc5KX3g') AND `tsection` IN(1,4) AND `social_type` = '2' AND `tfrom` != '94736' AND `tsuccess` = '0' AND `no_active` = '0'
  ORDER BY `sort` DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Значения для NOT IN берутся из отдельной таблицы.

Explain результат - http://c2n.me/3aAJrng.png

Индексы стоят на:

- turl_full
- tsection
- social_type
- tfrom
- tsuccess
- no_active
- sort

**UPD:**

Если убрать из запроса `tsuccess = 0`, то EXPLAIN extra показывает только Using where, значит всё хорошо. Но мне нужно это условие. С чем связано, что убирая tsuccess = 0 всё становится нормально?

Что я делаю не так? :/

Comment: @ModaL, эту махину будет сложно раскрутить без объяснения происхождения условий и общей картины.

Comment: @Etki, добавил, что значения для NOT IN берутся из отдельной таблицы. Собственно больше и нечего рассказать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я правильно понимаю, что для получения результата вы сначала ищете 900 с лишним записей, а затем берете первую из них? Почему нельзя задать запрос с более точными условиями для получения одной записи?

Comment: @Get, это точный запрос. Если Вы про NOT IN, то эти данные получаются с другой таблицы.